# automatic label numbering

Tags: hyperref

My document first contains a series of exercises and then their correction.

To number the same as the exercises, I used the command `\setcounter{section}{0}` before the corrections

I also want to add the page number corresponding to the correction of each exercise: so I created labels with `\label{XXX}` to indicate the page number with `\pageref{XXX}` using the package`hyperref`

This solution works but is not optimized. For example, is it possible to number the labels and associate them with the same counter as that of the sections?

Could I not automatically use the same number between the section of an exercise and the correction without having to reset the counter before the corrections? Especially since if I insert a new exercise in the middle, I must place my correction in the middle of the other corrections to keep the same number

thanks for your advices

Comment: \label uses values from the last (local) \refstepcounter.  Alternativley, you can set \@currentlabel, \@currentlabelname and \@currentHref manually.

Comment: @JohnKormylo : do you have any documentation on this subject ?

Comment: Source2e.pdf (available from CTAN) pages 463-464 for the default. See hyperref source for the redefined versions.  Also, look in the aux file for \newlabel.  There are several examples here on how to use \@currentlabel etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several packages for typesetting exams (or other collections of problems and solutions).

I used the `answers` package for a similar task a while back, to write question and answer together, and have LaTeX split it into questions and answers in separate files.

Comment: the problem with this type of package (I had seen the exams package) is that the solution follows the exercise while I would like to have all the exercises then all the corrections

Comment: @Nicolas Doesn't apply for all such packages I think, `xsim` for example seems to let you print solutions by themselves.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I don't think this package does what I'm looking for: I would like to have the list of exercises (all in a row) then the list of corrections (in the same order). A bit like in a book where each chapter ends with a series of exercises and whose corrections are found at the end of the book

Comment: @Nicolas `xsim` can do exactly that ... E.g. https://gist.github.com/TorbjornT/f5c449ba4aa24b81a8e8bd022068e042

Comment: @TorbjørnT. To be perfect (compared to my research because your idea has already advanced me a lot), can we add the page associated with each correction?

Comment: @Nicolas I don't know.

Comment: @Nicolas, the `answers` package gives quite a leeway when writing out the files. You certainly should be able to add a `pageref` to the question somewhere.

Comment: @TorbjørnT., thanks for the reference to `xsim`! It looks much cleaner than my manual `answers` solution. I'll try it out soonish.